# Determining if a Vector is a member of a Convex Hull

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-hulls, convex-cone, decision-problems

**Edit:** Here is how the following sets are created:

$S$ is the set of all $n$-dimensional, multilinear trinomials that are strictly greater than $0$ on the interval $[0,1]^n$. $T$ are all miltilinear trinomials such that they are non-negative, but have a $0$ on said interval. I was contemplating expanding out my search criteria into making it polynomials, rather than multilinear trinomials to see if that becomes easier.

---

Say I have two particular sets of $n$ dimensional vectors $S, T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Given some vector $x$, I want to know if $x$ is on the interior of $S$. Here are some properties of my sets.

1. $S$ and $T$ are disjoint sets. They also are both infinite.
2. $S$ is bounded on one side, but does not include its boundary (imagine the right half plane). I *believe* that $T=\partial S$, but I'm not sure, so I'd only like to use this assumption if necessary.
3. $S$ is a convex set. Not only that, it actually is also a convex hull being closed under positive scalar addition. I think this also more strongly classifies it as a convex cone as well.
4. It is easy to generate new points in either $S$ or $T$

My question is if there is a known algorithm or method for determining whether a given vector $x$ is a member of the interior of $S$ given $S$ is a convex hull. If so, how many points would we need from $S$ to use to guarantee that our method works? I did a little research to see that the finite case can be reduced to linear programming, but I haven't seen anything for the infinite case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How exactly is $S$ described/given to you? To run any sort of algorithm, presumably there's some sort of implicit description of $S$ via a set of inequalities or an oracle or something else...

Comment: It is an interesting situation if you say that it is easy to generate points in $S$, but it is not easy to check membership in $S$. Does it not mean that the points you can generate are of some special, simple form, and therefore they are likely not to generate the whole $S$ too well? Or how does generating points in $S$ work? It would be helpful if you wrote more context.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde I added descriptions of the sets hopefully that helps!

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Its not that I know it is not easy to check for membership in $S$, I just generally have no idea how one would go about checking membership in an infinite convex hull! I also added criteria for what makes up each set. How would one go about generating the entirety of $S$ from finite points? How many points would I need?

Comment: Wait, sorry if I'm misunderstanding things, but $S$ is the set of all polynomials in $n$ variables that can be expressed as a linear combination of at most three monomials, such that the maximum degree of any variable in any monomial is at most $1$? If that's right, this isn't convex, as the convex combination of two such polynomials may not still be a trinomial...

Comment: @JasonGaitonde I should have clarified, I mean multilinear polynomials of max degree $3$ or less. That should be convex unless I've made a horrible error

Comment: Ah okay I see. Unless I'm missing something else, isn't $f\in S$ if and only if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ by multilinearity? One direction is by definition of $S$ and the other is that for $x\in [0,1]^n$, you can write $f(x)$ as a convex combination of the values on the hypercube. Doesn't this give you a way to check membership in $S$? Also, isn't $S$ itself open when each $f$ is written as a vector of coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^{{n \choose 3}}$?

Comment: @JasonGaitonde I am not sure I am following your argument 100% (I'm sorry I am just an undergrad student and I haven't had a course on this), but that would require $2^n$ computations and I was hoping to see if there was a membership algorithm that could be derived from other points that only required polynomial time. 

Also yes the vectors of coefficients are also open, assuming I understood what you meant. Again totally sorry for my lack of knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the set of multilinear polynomials with degree at most $3$ on $n$ variables. To expand on my comment, a polynomial $f\in S$ (or more generally, any multilinear polynomial) is nonnegative (positive) on $[0,1]^n$ if and only if it is nonnegative (positive) on $\{0,1\}^n$, so it suffices to check $2^n$ points. Note that $f$ is multilinear if and only if it can be written as $f(x)=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]} c_S \prod_{i\in S}x_i$. In your specific case, the sum is actually over all $S\subseteq [n]$ with $\vert S\vert\leq 3$.

One direction is immediate. To show this is sufficient, fix $x\in [0,1]^n$ and we will write $f(x)$ as a convex combination of the values on $\{0,1\}^n$. To do this, define a random variable $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ where the components are independent and $y_i=1$ with probability $x_i$ and is $0$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb{E}[y_i]=x_i$, and so 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_y[f(y)]=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]} c_S \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in S} y_i]=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]} c_S \prod_{i\in S}\mathbb{E}[ y_i]=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]} c_S \prod_{i\in S} x_i=f(x).
\end{equation}
Note we use independence in the second equality. As $y$ is supported in $\{0,1\}^n$, this means $f(x)$ is a convex combination (average) of values on this subset, so if $f$ is nonnegative (positive) on all such points, it will be nonnegative (positive) on any $x\in [0,1]^n$. So to test membership in $S$, you can check just those $2^n$ points instead of infinitely many points.

As for can you do better in general; the answer is likely no. The reason is that testing the nonnegativity of multilinear polynomials on $\{0,1\}^n$ encodes many $NP$-hard problems. For instance, it is not too hard to write (a version of) the MAXCUT problem as a degree $2$ multilinear polynomial, so if you could determine whether a multilinear polynomial is nonnegative on $\{0,1\}^n$ in polynomial time, then you would have shown that $P=NP$.

In some cases, though, you might be able to certify nonnegativity faster. One method is the so-called sum-of-squares hierarchy; the idea is that if you can show your polynomial is equal to a sum of squares of other polynomials on $\{0,1\}^n$ (as in, takes the same values on that set), then it must be nonnegative on that set. If it can be written as a sum of squares of polynomials of degree at most $d/2$, then $f$ is said to have a certificate of nonnegativity of degree $d$. It is possible to show that every nonnegative multilinear polynomial on $\{0,1\}^n$ has such a certificate of degree at most $2n$. The amazing thing is that there is a way essentially using SDPs to determine in time $n^{O(d)}$ whether a given $f$ has such a certificate of nonnegativity of degree $d$, or a proof (sometimes called a pseudodistribution) that it doesn't. So in the cases that your $f$ has a low-degree certificate, it is possible to prove it in polynomial time (if $d$ is a constant i.e. does not grow with $n$). There is a lot of research now to determine the extent to which this framework can solve problems that are very likely computationally hard. [These notes by Boaz Barak and David Steurer](https://www.sumofsquares.org/public/index.html) are pretty good if you're interested.